# How to get url address of current redirecting page

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I can navigate to one view in two ways:

```
http://test.new.loc/ru/cabinet/intranet/update/
```

and  `http://test.new.loc/ru/plaint`

I used `$this->redirect(array('/plaint'));`in actionUpdate action (for this url `http://test.new.loc/ru/cabinet/intranet/update/` ) to redirect to this `http://test.new.loc/ru/plaint` page .
I used following code   var_dump(Yii::app()->controller->action->id);, but it returns `/plaint`. But, I need to get `/intranet/update/` url. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Check it out...

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Thanks